# Calling method twice in same block. Why?

Tags: java, optimization, jvm, compiler-optimization

I'm reading a blog post and trying to understand what's going on.
[This is the blogpost.](https://martinfowler.com/articles/replaceThrowWithNotification.html)

it has this code:

```
if (validation().hasErrors()) 
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(validation().errorMessage());
```

In the validation() method we have some object initialization and calculations so let' say it's an expensive call. Is it going to be executed twice? Or will it be optimized by the compiler to be something like this?

```
var validation = validation();
if (validation.hasErrors()) 
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(validation.errorMessage());
```

Thanks!

Comment: [Is JVM or JIT able to reduce duplicate method calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74106557/2711488) has been asked just a few days ago. But don’t worry, `validation()` is only invoked twice in the exceptional case, which might not be performance relevant at all. Instead, you should ask yourself the real question: is the suggested refactoring that requires the caller to invoke `hasErrors()` instead of throwing exceptions directly, really a good idea? Offering the possibility to ignore errors and continue, leads to exactly that, ignoring errors. How often do you check `System.out.checkError()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The validation method will be called twice, and it will do the same work each time. First, the method is relatively big, and so it won't get inlined. Without being inlined, the compiler doesn't know what it does. Therefore, it safely assumes that the method has side effects, and so it cannot optimize away the second call.

Even if the method was inlined, and the compiler could examine it, it would see that there are in fact side effects. Calling LocalDate.now() returns a different result each time. For this reason, the code that you linked to is defective, although it's not likely to experience a problem in practice.

It's safer to capture the validation result in a local variable not for performance reasons, but for stability reasons. Imagine the odd case in which the initial validation call fails, but the second call passes. You'd then throw an exception with no message in it.

Answer (score 2):

The Java to Bytecode compiler has a limited set of optimization techniques (e.g. 9*9 in the condition would turn into 81).

The real optimization happens by the JIT (Just In Time) compiler. This compiler is the result of over a decade and a half of extensive research and there is no simple answer to tell what it is capable of in every scenario.

With that being said, as a good practice, I always handle repetitive identical method calls by storing their result before approaching any loop structure where that result is needed. Example:

```
int[] grades = new int[500];
int countOfGrades = arr.length;
for (int i = 0; i < countOfGrades; i++) {
    // Some code here
}
```

For your code (which is only run twice), you shouldn't worry as much about such optimization. But if you're looking for the ultimate – guaranteed – optimization on the account of a fraction of space (which is cheap), then you're better off using a variable to store any **identical** method result when needed more than once:

```
var validation = validation();
if (validation.hasErrors()) 
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(validation.errorMessage());
```

Comment: Another benefit to having a named variable containing a calculated result: Naming makes it more [self-documenting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code). In your example here, I would name `short length` to be `short countOfWhatever`, with "Whatever" being the subject matter at hand.

Comment: By the way… I may be wrong, but I vaguely recall that `short` does not save memory in modern implementations of Java. That may explain why they added `…IntExact` & `…LongExact` methods in the [`Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html) class, but no `…ShortExact` methods.

Comment: @BasilBourque I remember there's padding involved, in order to avoid any CPU performance hits that accompany upholding various requirements to do non-standard (e.g. short operations) on the macro level, as opposed to just having 32-bit or 64-bit operand operations.

Comment: Regardless of the `short` issue, your overall point is wise, and should be heeded.

Comment: @BasilBourque in fact, using `short` for local variables *never* saved memory because there are no short variables in compiled code. Java uses `int` arithmetic for all integer types except `long`. That’s even [specified on the language level](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2:~:text=Otherwise,type%20int%20by%20numeric%20promotion.). That’s why `i++` for a `short` variable is short-hand for `i = (short)(i + 1)`, requiring five bytecode instructions where `i++` for `int` compiles to a single instruction. Using `short` here makes the code worse on all levels.

Comment: @Holger I was only under the habit of using ‘short’ for when I use other programing languages that benefit from the use of the short data type. With that being said, since we’re talking about Java here, I’ve just replaced ‘short’ with ‘int’ and emitted the part about the ‘short’ usage. Thank you!

Comment: If you don’t need the index `i` in the loop body, you can just write `for(int grade: grades) { … }` Even for the other programming languages, it’s rather unlikely to draw a benefit from using `short` *for a loop counter*. Using smaller data types becomes relevant when using heap variable, most notably arrays.

Answer (score -4):

However, I must simply question ... *"these days,"* does it even actually **matter** anymore?  Simply write the source-code "in the most obvious manner available," as the original programmer certainly did.

"Microseconds" really don't matter anymore.  But, **"clarity** still does."  To me, the first version of the code is frankly more ***understandable*** than the second, and "that's what matters to me most."  Please don't bother to try to *"out-smart"* the compiler, if it results in source-code that is in any way harder to understand.

Comment: Clarity is of course important, but storing a function call's result is actually sometimes more readable. This is especially true when you have nested function calls where the result of one call is called upon in another: In this case, it's more readable to store it in a separate variable. We should also not forget that the most important aspect of a program is the user's experience – after all, all the user cares about is the speed of the program, and I don't think it's a good practice to convenience yourself as a programer on the expense of the user's convenience.

Comment: "It doesn't matter" is at *best* a comment or footnote on specific questions about how certain compilers work, whether they're able to do certain optimizations.  It's true most of the time, but that doesn't invalidate the question for the purposes of curiosity.  I guess the actual point of your answer was about clarity for human readers, which is fine and could be a good answer if people agreed with you about the clarity.  I think Holger's point in a comment under the question makes sense: you're getting a message from a different return value than the error, so they might not match.